# Deallocating memory of a 2D array of pointers only till a certain limit

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers

I have a 2D array created dynamically using pointer. I want to delete only certain continuous rows, not all of them. Here is the code I have written for deleting:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void clearMemoryAll(int **matchedIndicesArray, int rows)
{

  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
    delete [] matchedIndicesArray[i];
  }

  delete [] matchedIndicesArray;

}

int main()
{
  // Program having 10M x 4 = 40M elements

  int rows = 10000000;
  int **matchedStagesMatrix;
  matchedStagesMatrix = new int*[rows];

  int cols = 4;


  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
    matchedStagesMatrix[i] = new int[cols];
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
      matchedStagesMatrix[i][j] = 1;
    }
  }



  clearMemoryAll(matchedStagesMatrix, rows);
  while (1) {}


  return 0;
}
```

Clearly, this code is gonna delete ALL the rows of the 2D array. How do I delete only certain first 100 rows instead of all at once? I can't simply pass 100 as a parameter to the function since it'd anyways try to delete complete matrix when the control reaches outside the function's for loop. The matrix should be deleted such that it should still be usable after deleting certain rows.
I understand vectors is a good alternative, but I'm curious about how pointers work and how they can be manipulated instead of using vectors.

**Edit**: Also, I plan to use this delete function numerous times, i.e. I'd be deleting the matrix rows one by one numerous times, each time only certain few rows until all the rows are deleted. Therefore, the last line outside for loop cannot be executed every time.

Comment: Isn't using vectors an option?

Comment: Let's say, this has to be done using pointers rather than vectors.

Comment: You can use vectors of pointers to achieve this and deleting would be easier

Comment: Pass values that represent the first and last indices to be `delete`d, and loop accordingly.     You'll need to decide whether to do `delete [] matchedIndicesArray;` or not, and also work out how to avoid deleting rows more than once if the the function is called more than once with overlapping ranges  (since deleting something twice gives undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are other ways to do the task that you want to do, but let's say that we stick to the way that you have discussed in the question.

**If you delete a certain row, you need to remember which row you deleted and make sure not to access it again.**

For this, you can maintain an array of flags, which has the size equal to number of rows. The flags are all 0 at first.

Example - If there are total 10 rows in the 2D array, then

```
int flag[rows] = 0;
```

When you delete a certain row, you can change the value of flag for that row to 1.

Example - if we delete 4th row, then

```
flag[3] = 1;
```

After that whenever you have to traverse through the 2D array, you can just skip the row which has value of flag equal to 1.

Here, is the sample code, modified by me:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void printArray(int **matchedIndicesArray,int flag[], int rows, int cols)
{
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++)
    {
    if(flag[i]==1)    //if flag for the row is 1, that means it is deleted, and so we skip it
    {
      continue;
    }
        for(int j=0; j<cols; j++)
        {
            cout<<matchedIndicesArray[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<endl;
}

void clearMemorySome(int **matchedIndicesArray, int flag[], int rows)
{

  for(int i = 0; i < rows/2; i++)  //here I chose to delete half the rows
  {
    delete [] matchedIndicesArray[i];
    flag[i] = 1;   //to remember which row has been deleted, we change the value of flag to 1
  }
  return;
  //delete [] matchedIndicesArray;   //this is commented out because we are only deleting certain rows at a time

}

int main()
{
  // Program having 10 * 3 = 30 elements

  int rows = 10;
  int **matchedStagesMatrix;
  matchedStagesMatrix = new int*[rows];

  int cols = 3;

  int flag[rows]={0};    //initially the flag value for every row is 0

  for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
  {
    matchedStagesMatrix[i] = new int[cols];
    for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
    {
      matchedStagesMatrix[i][j] = 1;
    }
  }

  cout<<"The 2D array before half of the rows are deleted\n";
  printArray(matchedStagesMatrix, flag, rows, cols);

  clearMemorySome(matchedStagesMatrix, flag, rows);
  cout<<"The 2D array after half of the rows are deleted\n";
  printArray(matchedStagesMatrix, flag, rows, cols);

  return 0;
}
```

The output of the above code is:

> The 2D array before half of the rows are deleted
>
> 1 1 1   1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1
>
> The 2D array after half of the rows are deleted
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1
>
> 1 1 1

Comment: Since we're not using `delete [] matchedIndicesArray` at all, are we sure that memory is efficiently and properly deallocated? I mean, we are just deleting rows, but not the array holding the rows, right?

Comment: Yes. In a 2D array constructed using pointers, we first delete pointers to the rows and then the main pointer. Since, here we are not deleting all the pointers to the rows, we must not delete the main pointer. But once, you delete all rows you can delete the main pointer as well. You can implement that by checking if all the flags are 1, if they are you must then delete the main pointer as well.

Comment: So is there a way to delete the main pointer after all the rows are deleted, because I tried doing that and it gives a double free or corruption error. What could be the reason for that?

Comment: You can delete the main pointer immediately after you delete the last remaining row. I tried it out and it works. For that, you will have to keep track of the remaining rows. If remaining_rows==1, then after deleting that row, you must delete the main pointer as well.

Answer (score 3):

This can be done if you use vectors, which are easier to handle thanks to their methods.

```
int n,x;
std::cin>>n>>x;
std::vector<int*> myVec;
int* row=new int[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    std::cin>>row[i];
myVec.push_back(row);
//do this for all your rows;
myVec.erase(myVec.begin(),myVec.end()+x); //delete first x rows;
//you can play with the line above to delete lines in a range or sth
```